# Why does this Mathematica function behave this way?

Tags: functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

I'm really confused by the behavior of this function:

```
david[x_] := 5; 6; 7

david[]
```

returns

```
7
```

but `david[3]` returns `5`

Why does this happen? I'd think the second case should also return 7; why doesn't it?

Comment: No: the line "david[x_] := 5;6;7" returns 7.  david[] returns david[] -- didn't you notice that line?  (You didn't say anything about a 0-argument function so it doesn't evaluate).

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, the function is not misbehaving. In fact, its behavior is correct. After you defined the function david, you terminated it with a semi-colon, which was then followed by a constant (6), whose value is suppressed by the semi-colon, then a constant which is unsuppressed. Thus, when you try to evaluate the cell, the value of the function david is set to give 5, every time it is run:

```
david[x_] := 5; (* This is where the 5 comes from when you try to evaluate the cell*)
```

**The fact that you get 7 is because you have an unsuppressed constant.**

Compare to this:

```
david[x_] := 5; 6; 7; 9; 12; (* 6, 7, 9 and 12 will never show up, since they are suppressed *)
```

Versus:

```
david[x_] := 5; 6; 7; 9; 12; 17 (* 17 will **always** show up, since it is unsuppressed *)
```

What you have observed is one of the quirks of the Mathematica language.

Comment: So how do I create functions that use multiple statments?

Comment: By using Switch. Example (taken from here): [In10](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Conditionals.html) 

`r[x_] := Switch[Mod[x, 3], 0, a, 1, b, 2, c]`

Which, when run, will return the values (a, b or c) depending on the mod of the input number. Example: Mo[7,3] returns 2, therefore the return value of r[10] will be b (the return value of case 2 as defined above).

Comment: I mean I want to make functions that really have multiple statments. Like a method in a real program. e.g. function doSomething(){result; manipulate result; manimpulate result more; again; return result; }

Comment: You don't need to use Module. For example `f[x_] := (Print@x; Print@x); f[4]`

Comment: Make your function a "Block" (or "Module") - it can be arbitrarily long, and have as many statements as you wish, and it has a 'return value' (either via the "Return" keyword, or as the final value of the "Block").  And as belisarius says, the "mathematica.stackexchange.com" is definitely the place to go.